# CSS: drop down menu doesn't display when navbar is repositioned

Tags: html, css

I want to reposition my navbar. In its current position:

```
    #navbar ul {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #5D2C2C;
/*position: relative;
bottom: 115px;*/
}

    #navbar ul li {
float: left;
/*position: relative;
left: 420px;*/
}

#navbar li li {
display: none;
}

#navbar li:hover li {
display: block;
width: inherit;
}

#navbar a {
font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

the dropdown displays correctly
[image: menu drops down and 2 options can be seen]

but when I remove the /* comments */ so the bar is correctly positioned, the menu drops down but the two items aren't showing and I cannot find out why

[image: drop down menu showing no options]

the HTML if needed:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
        <li><a href="#intro">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#history">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#national">National Flags</a></li>
        <li><a href="#maritime">International Maritime Signal Flags</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#letters">Maritme Signals: Letters</a></li>
                <li><a href="#numbers">Maritme Signals: Numbers </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```